# Calculating a new column from a lookup returns "cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, indexing

I am getting a

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

when trying to create a new Dataframe column by multiplying an existing one with a value looked up from another Dataframe. Any idea?

```
data = {'country':['Eurozone', 'Sweden', 'USA', 'Japan'],
        'currency':['EUR','SEK','USD','JPY'],
        'forex':[1,2,10.5,5.3]}
ref = pd.DataFrame(data)
ref.set_index('currency', inplace=True)

data2 = {'salary':[10,11,12,13,14],
        'currency':['EUR','EUR','USD','SEK','JPY'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df['salary_eur'] = df['salary'] * ref.loc[df['currency']].forex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the currencies:

```
df['salary_eur'] = df['salary'] * df['currency'].map(ref['forex'])
```

Output:

```
   salary currency  salary_eur
0      10      EUR        10.0
1      11      EUR        11.0
2      12      USD       126.0
3      13      SEK        26.0
4      14      JPY        74.2
```

Comment: @Plantigrade you're welcome

Comment: Hey @mozway : thanks, that solved my problem! (Sorry looks like my earlier comment either did not post or was removed?)